# Microsoft Graph Secure score refresh interval

Tags: security, microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft secure score API provides score for Office 365 configurations. It provides list of best practices to secure O365 account. If we fix the mentioned issue and when we retrieve the secure score results again, we are getting same old result. As per Microsoft documentation, secure score should be updated daily but it is not happening. Any idea about its refresh frequency?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/securescores

Comment: Is it refreshed now?

Answer (score 0):

The official document explains it like this:

> The score is calculated once per day (around 1:00 AM PST). If you
> make a change to a measured action, the score will automatically
> update the next day. It takes up to 48 hours for a change to be
> reflected in your score.

According to the documentation, the score should be calculated once a day, starting at about 1:00 AM Pacific time, but it will take several hours to run. There are also instances where the job fails and we need to restart it so this might be why you don't see it updated at the exact same time every day.

Moreover, it may take up to 48 hours to refresh, so I suggest you wait until 48 hours to see if it refreshes.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.).This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @GaneshM  As I said in the answer, the refresh can take up to 48 hours, so I suggest you wait until 48 hours to see if it refreshes.